# outlook 2007 or 2010 doesn't support the background property

Tags: html, outlook, background-color, newsletter, fieldset

i am creating a newsletter which is send via email and in this newletter i am trying to use the `<fieldset></fieldset>`  or `<legend></legend>` tag and when i give the background color its work on browsers but when i see on the outlook 2007 and 2010 it doesn't work below is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <fieldset style="border-left: 1px solid #99CCFF; border-right: 1px solid #99CCFF;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #99CCFF; border-top: 1px solid #99CCFF; padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px; background-color:#CD853F; height:300px; width:300px;">
        <legend style="font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase;">Warranty Items</legend>
        <span style="padding-bottom: 300px;">** Content here ***</span>
    </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? The tags themselves, or the background colour?

Answer (score 1):

Never used `<fieldset>` or `<legend>` tags, but you need to use the `<body>` tag or MS VML to get Outlook to display background images. This might be useful to you: [emailbg.net](http://emailbg.net/)